# Adding unique identifier based on repeating values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using MS-SQL, I have the following table excerpt:

```
-----------------------------------
Market | Cycle | Milestone | Sale |
  A    | NULL  |  NULL     | NULL | 
  A    |   1   |  NULL     | NULL | 
  B    | NULL  |  NULL     | NULL | 
  B    |   3   |     4     | NULL | 
  B    |   3   |     4     |  5   | 
  A    |   1   |     2     | NULL | 
  A    |   1   |     2     |  1   | 
 NULL  |   C   |     6     |  7   | 
 NULL  |   C   |  NULL     | NULL | 
  D    |   8   |  NULL     | NULL | 
  D    |   8   |     9     | NULL |
```

Each row represents a new stage in the product life-cycle.
If the first stage of product C was Cycle, the next row for it will have values in Cycle and Milestone, and so forth.
I need to add an identifier for each group, based on the first not-null column for each value.

The required output for the above table would be as follows:

```
-------------------------------------------
Market | Cycle | Milestone | Sale | Group
  A    | NULL  |  NULL     | NULL |   1
  A    |   1   |  NULL     | NULL |   1
  B    | NULL  |  NULL     | NULL |   2
  B    |   3   |     4     | NULL |   2
  B    |   3   |     4     |  5   |   2
  A    |   1   |     2     | NULL |   1
  A    |   1   |     2     |  1   |   1
 NULL  |   C   |     6     |  7   |   3
 NULL  |   C   |  NULL     | NULL |   3
  D    |   8   |  NULL     | NULL |   4
  D    |   8   |     9     | NULL |   4
```

If a new row will be added with Market "D", it will receive Group 1.
If a new row will be added with Market Null and Cycle which has no appeared yet, it will start a new group 5. Future rows with the same cycle will also receive 5.

Hopefully this is clear enough...
Any assistance with SQL-Server code for this will be helpful.
Thank you!

Comment: Did you try anything? Maybe `DENSE_RANK()`?

Comment: What column orders the rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will set the `Group` value in the way you want, although it seems inelegant:

```
UPDATE tblGroup
SET Group = ASCII(COALESCE(Market, Cycle, Milestone, Sale)) - 64
```

...or select it via:

```
SELECT *, ASCII(COALESCE(Market, Cycle, Milestone, Sale)) - 64 AS Group
FROM tblGroup
```

Comment: Thank you @strickt01, I tried rank, dense_rank, groupby...

Using COALESCE with DENSE_RANK solved this! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Y-O Where is _"COALESCE with DENSE_RANK"_ here?

Comment: @strickt01 -- Can you please tell why are we doing "-64" in your query. Thanks

Comment: @Sami The `COALESCE` is essential to return the results requested. Using `ASCII` as opposed to `DENSE_RANK` is quicker but less flexible as it relies on the codes being A, B, C, D etc.

Comment: @balaji `ASCII` on the character "A" will return 65, "B" 66 etc. So subtracting 64 gets you 1, 2 etc. as required by @Y-O.

Comment: @strickt01 That will works only when assuming other column are `Varchar/Nvarchar` data types. Otherwise it will throw a conversion error

Comment: @Sami the same applies to your solution if you `COALESCE` over all four columns, which is a requirement. If the other columns are to hold string values such as 'A', 'B' etc they will need to be varchar/nvarchar.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a window function as

```
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Market) [Group]
-- Or DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COALESCE(Market, Cycle)) [Group] to get the exact results 
FROM
(
  VALUES
  ('A',  NULL, NULL, NULL),
  ('A',  '1', NULL, NULL),
  ('B',  NULL, NULL, NULL),
  ('B',  '3',    4, NULL), 
  ('B',  '3',    4,  5  ), 
  ('A',  '1',    2, NULL), 
  ('A',  '1',    2,  1  ), 
  (NULL, 'C',    6,  7  ), 
  (NULL, 'C', NULL, NULL), 
  ('D',  '8', NULL, NULL), 
  ('D',  '8',    9, NULL)
)T(Market, Cycle, Milestone, Sale)
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6bbfe2cd7f8becfb420d2ef319eae37e)**</kbd>